# How to optimize query? Explain Plan

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have one table with 3 fields and I neeed get all value of fields, I have next query:

```
SELECT COM.FIELD1, COM.FIELD2, COM.FIELD3 
    FROM OWNER.TABLE_NAME COM 
        WHERE COM.FIELD1 <> V_FIELD 
            ORDER BY COM.FIELD3 ASC;
```

And i want optimaze, I have next values of explain plan:

```
            Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  CHOOSECost: 4  Bytes: 90  Cardinality: 6          
    2 SORT ORDER BY  Cost: 4  Bytes: 90  Cardinality: 6     
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL OWNER.TABLE_NAME Cost: 2  Bytes: 90  Cardinality: 6
```

Any solution for not get TAF(Table Acces Full)?

Thanks!

Comment: How can we get explain Plan for a query?

Comment: Do this in sqlplus:  alter session set statistics_level=ALL; run the query; then run select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST' ) );  Then past the output of the execution plan

Comment: Question for know how get "explain plan" or question my question?

Comment: "not get TAF(Table Acces Full)?" full table scans are not always bad. And without a functional index you can't do an index lookup on '<>'

Comment: @5frags - answers to your question will be posted as Answers, not as Comments. The side discussion of Explain Plan in the Comments may be distracting, but it is not really "out of bounds".

Answer (score 0):

Since your WHERE condition is on the column FIELD1, an index on that column many help.

You may already have an index on that column. Even then, you will still see a full table access, if the expected number of rows that don't have `VAL1` in that column is sufficiently large.

The only case when you will NOT see full table access is if you have an index on that column, the vast majority (at least, say, 80% to 90%) of rows in the table **do** have the value `VAL1` in the column `FIELD1`, and statistics are up to date AND, perhaps, you need to use a histogram (because in this case the distribution of values in `FIELD1` would be very skewed).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your table has a very large number of rows with a given key (let call it `'B'`) and a very small number of rows with other keys.

*Note, that the index access will work only for conditions `FIELD1 <> 'B'`, all  other predicates will return 'B' and therefore are not suitable for index access.*

*Note also that if you have  more that one large key, the index access will not work from the same reason - you will never get only a few record where index can profit*.

As a starting point you can reformulte the predicate

```
 FIELD1 <> V_FIELD
```

as

```
 DECODE(FIELD1,V_FIELD,1,0) = 0
```

The `DECODE` return 1 if `FIELD1 = V_FIELD` and returns 0 if  `FIELD1 <> V_FIELD`

This transformation allows you to define a function based index with the `DECODE` expression.

**Example**

```
create table tt as
select 
 decode(mod(rownum,10000),1,'A','B') FIELD1
from dual connect by level <= 50000;

select field1, count(*) from tt group by field1;

FIELD1   COUNT(*)
------ ----------
A               5 
B           49995
```

**FBIndex**

```
 create index tti on tt(decode(field1,'B',1,0));
```

Use your *large key* for the index definition.

**Access**

To select `FIELD1 <> 'B'` use reformulated predicate `decode(field1,'B',1,0) = 0`

Which leads nicely to an index access:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
 SELECT * from tt where decode(field1,'B',1,0) = 0;   
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL')); 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |      |   471 |  2355 |    24   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TT   |   471 |  2355 |    24   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TTI  |   188 |       |    49   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(DECODE("FIELD1",'B',1,0)=0)
```

To select `FIELD1 <> 'A'` use reformulated predicate `decode(field1,'A',1,0) = 0`

Here you don't want index access as nearly the whole table is returned- and the CBO opens FULL TABLE SCAN.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
 SELECT * from tt where decode(field1,'A',1,0) = 0;   
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      | 47066 | 94132 |    26   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TT   | 47066 | 94132 |    26   (4)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(DECODE("FIELD1",'A',1,0)=0)
```

**Bind Variables**

This will work the same way even if you use bind variables `FIELD1 <> V_FIELD` - provided you pass always the same value.

The [bind variable peeking](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/PFGRF/optimops.htm#PFGRF94588) will evaluate the correct plan in the first parse and generate the proper plan.

If you will use more that one values as bind variable (and therefore expect to get different plans for different values) - you will learn the feature of [adaptive cursor sharing](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/adaptive-cursor-sharing-11gr1)

Answer (score 0):

The query is already optimized, don't spend any more time on it unless it's running noticeably slow.  If you have a tuning checklist that says "avoid all full table scans" it might be time to change that checklist.

The cost of the full table scan is only *2*.  The exact meaning of the cost is tricky, and not always particularly helpful.  But in this case it's probably safe to say that 2 means the full table scan will run quickly.

If the query is not running in less than a few microseconds, or is returning significantly more than the estimated 6 rows, then there may be a problem with the optimizer statistics.  If that's the case, try gathering statistics like this:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('OWNER', 'TABLE_NAME');
end;
/
```

As @symcbean pointed out, a full table scan is not always a bad thing.  If a table is incredibly small, like this one might be, all the data may fit inside a single block.  (Oracle accesses data by block(s)-at-a-time, where the block is usually 8KB of data.)  When the data structures are trivially small there won't be any significant difference between using a table or an index.

Also, full table scans can use multi-block reads, whereas most index access paths use single-block reads.  For reading a large percentage of data it's faster to read the whole thing with multi-block reads than reading it one-block-at-a-time with an index.  Since this query only has a `<>` condition, it looks likely that this query will read a large percentage of data and a full table scan is optimal.